# How to handle JSON data which has = and : characters in json value in Android

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

Below is the JSON response I am getting for API requests.

**user = {
'name':'Siva',
'address':'my address',
'pincode':12345,
'url':'http://myweb.com/index.php?title=firstname:lastname+middlename&action=edit'
}**

As this JSON response started with **user =**  its neither JSONObject nor JSONArray. 
So I considered this as String and i split the response

```
String[] response = responseBody.split("=");

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

User user = gson.fromJson(response[1], User.class);
```

This is causing MalformedJsonException like below

**Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated string at line 5 column 47 path $.url**

I observed that value for url key is causing issues. Because it has = and : characters in url value. But i did not find the proper solution.

Can anybody help me on how to handle this.

Comment: I am confused, what do you mean song= also even if it is not JsonObject, you should parse it to become Json object. It will make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: @Bqin, It is my typo error. Updated the post. Can you please check.

Comment: Create a class which matches above parameters and map the Json object by Using jsonParse(string value, object.class) this would make things easier

Comment: Your JSON is not valid . you have to change your response in backhend code . And use `:` instead of `=` .

Comment: @SajidhZahir, Can you provide one example with jsonParse(string value, object.class) . I am getting confused, how to handle this.

Comment: Also the part after the `=` is not valid JSON. It should use double quotes instead of the single quotes.

Comment: What if you encode the url before parsing it as a Json value so it would look something like this "http%3A%2F%2Fmyweb.com%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3Dfirstname%3Alastname%2Bmiddlename%26action%3Dedit" and decode it back when using ? This would work only if you have got backend Api access

Comment: @Henry, Json works with single quotes also.

Comment: @SajidhZahir, I do not have access to backend API :-(

Comment: @PolamNaganji no, it doesn't. See the specification: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159 Some tools may accept single quotes, but technically that's not JSON anymore.

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the information. I am using Gson, So i am not getting issues with single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have been using gson could do something like this

```
    Gson g = new Gson();

Person person = g.fromJson(responsejsonstring, Person.class);
System.out.println(person.name); //Johnh@gmail.com

System.out.println(g.toJson(person)); // {"email":"Johnh@gmail.com"}
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it is not working. It is throwing the same exception as above. Is there any alternative for this. Thanks

Comment: Or you can give a try using  org Json library methods

Comment: JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(" response string ");
String url = obj.getJSONObject("user").getString("url ");

Answer (score 0):

After you get this in `response[1]`,

```
{ 'name':'Siva', 'address':'my address', 'pincode':12345, 'url':'http://myweb.com/index.php?title=firstname:lastname+middlename&action=edit' }
```

replace the `'` with `"` first. Like this,

```
response[1] = response[1].replaceAll("\'", "\"");
```

Check the response after that to be sure that all the `'` are actually replaced by `"`.

Then see if it parses afterwards.